# How to calculate the standard error of the slope in linear regression when performing a t-test against a value?

Tags: regression

I'm trying to understand the calculation of the t-statistic in a linear regression when you are testing against a specific value, i.e. using the formula
$$t=\frac{\hat{\beta}-\beta}{\text{S.E.}(\hat{\beta})}.$$
[t-statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-statistic#:%7E:text=The%20t%2Dstatistic%20is%20used,population%20standard%20deviation%20is%20unknown.) states that "$\text{S.E.}(\hat{\beta})$ is the standard error of the estimator ${\hat {\beta }}$ for $\beta$."

I understand how this works for $\beta=0$ (using $\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1})$ but I'm not sure how to generalise the calculation of $\text{S.E.}(\hat{\beta})$.

Comment: The equation you wrote is the generalization for $\beta != 0$.  If $E(\hat{\beta}) = \beta$ then $E(\hat{beta} - \beta) = 0$.  If I'm not right, can you be more specific about what you mean by "generalization"?  Can you tell us what kind of equation you are looking for?

Comment: @RCarnell apologies that was not clear, I meant the calculation of the standard error. Does this remain unchanged when $\beta!=0$?

Comment: The calculation of the standard error of $\hat{\beta}$ is only dependent on the sample.  So, yes, if the true $\beta$ is non-zero, the equation still works.